# Magento 1.6 Adding New Address Template

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to add a new address template to Magento 1.6, so I can output addresses formatted for labels in my shipments PDF as well as keeping the standard PDF address format.

So far I have copied the file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml to the local code pool and have copied the xml from an existing template and renamed it to . Below are the relevant parts of the config.xml

**Code:** 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml

**Part One:**

```
   <customer>
        <address>
            <formats>
                <text translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>Text</title>
                </text>
                <oneline translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>Text One Line</title>
                </oneline>
                <html translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>HTML</title>
                    <htmlEscape>true</htmlEscape>
                </html>
                <pdf translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>PDF</title>
                </pdf>
                <js_template template="title" module="customer">
                    <title>JavaScript Template</title>
                </js_template>
                <add_label template="title" module="customer">
                    <title>Address Label</title>
                </add_label>
            </formats>
        </address>
    </customer>
```

**Part Two:**

```
   <address_templates>
            <text>
                {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
                {{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
                {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
                {{/if}}
                {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
                {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
                {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
                {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
                {{var country}}
                T: {{var telephone}}
                {{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
                {{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
            </text>
            <oneline>{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}, {{var street}}, {{var city}}, {{var region}} {{var postcode}}, {{var country}}</oneline>
            <html>
                {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}&lt;br/&gt;
                {{depend company}}{{var company}}&lt;br /&gt;{{/depend}}
                {{if street1}}{{var street1}}&lt;br /&gt;{{/if}}
                {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}&lt;br /&gt;{{/depend}}
                {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}&lt;br /&gt;{{/depend}}
                {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}&lt;br /&gt;{{/depend}}
                {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}&lt;br/&gt;
                {{var country}}&lt;br/&gt;
                {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
                {{depend fax}}&lt;br/&gt;F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
                {{depend vat_id}}&lt;br/&gt;VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
            </html>
            <pdf>
                {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
                {{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
                {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
                {{/if}}
                {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
                {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
                {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
                {{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
                {{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
                {{var country}}|
                {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
                {{depend fax}}&lt;br/&gt;F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
                {{depend vat_id}}&lt;br/&gt;VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|
            </pdf>
            <js_template>#{prefix} #{firstname} #{middlename} #{lastname} #{suffix}&lt;br/&gt;#{company}&lt;br/&gt;#{street0}&lt;br/&gt;#{street1}&lt;br/&gt;#{street2}&lt;br/&gt;#{street3}&lt;br/&gt;#{city}, #{region}, #{postcode}&lt;br/&gt;#{country_id}&lt;br/&gt;T: #{telephone}&lt;br/&gt;F: #{fax}&lt;br/&gt;VAT: #{vat_id}</js_template>
            <add_label>
                {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
                {{depend company}}{{var company}},|{{/depend}}
                {{if street1}}{{var street1}},{{/if}}
                {{depend street2}}{{var street2}},|{{/depend}}
                {{depend street3}}{{var street3}},|{{/depend}}
                {{depend street4}}{{var street4}},|{{/depend}}
                {{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
                {{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
                {{var country}}|
            </add_label>
        </address_templates>
```

Then I copied app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php to the local code pool and tried to output my new address template with the following code.

**Code:** app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php

```
$shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getShippingAddress()->format('add_label'));

$this->y = 170;
foreach ($shippingAddress as $value){
    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($value)), 40, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
    $this->y -=10;
}
```

But what gets outputted is not my new address template it seems to be some sort of default template. I have refreshed the cache but this doesn't change anything. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**! Solved for Magento 1.7.0.2 - currently not tried in v1.6 !**

Inspired by your post I found a solution for an own address template.

Here's my module config of just a demo module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NAMESPACE_MODULE>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NAMESPACE_MODULE>
    </modules>
    <global>

        ...

        <customer>
            <address>
                <formats>
                    <html_special translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>HTML special</title>
                        <htmlEscape>true</htmlEscape>
                    </html_special>
                </formats>
            </address>
        </customer>

        ...

    </global>

    ...

    <default>
        <customer>
            <address_templates>
                <html_special><![CDATA[
MY SPECIAL HTML ADDRESS
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}} {{/if}}{{if city}}{{var city}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}Tel: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>Fax: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
                ]]></html_special>
            </address_templates>
        </customer>
    </default>

</config>
```

I guess you didn't put the `<address>...</address>` into the `<global>` block?!